# Galaxy S3 flip case: auto-lock when closed?

Tags: lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I have the Samsung flip case for my Samsung Galaxy S3. Is it possible to setup the phone to automatically lock when the case is closed, then to wake the screen when I open the flip case?

Is it also possible for me to get some sort of feedback from taps/touches on the phone, maybe a vibrate rather than the current tone it plays?

Comment: Please only ask one question per post.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use RFID labels for this action, but it's requires modding of case and software, what make some activities using NFC.